# Resolving a FQDN to a local server

Tags: domain-name-system, nat, fqdn

I have a domain name with WebFaction.  I created a new subdomain that I want to point to a local server behind a NAT firewall.  I can change the DNS records of the subdomain.  What do I change so the FQDN points to the local server?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you require that subdomain to be reachable outside your network? If not, then just point the A record of the subdomain to the IP address of your internal server.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  For curiosity's sake, how would I make it accessible outside my network?

Comment: Joe, this is a little more difficult: the best way would be to set the A record on your DNS host (your external host) to the public IP address of the server and place an entry in your hosts file/set an A record on your LOCAL DNS server that points to your internal IP address.